# Public names showing up under my home network

Tags: network-shares

Why do I show other computer networks under my network tab. I am showing my computer "HOME" but I also see four others that I have no idea who they are. Usually I can see WIFI networks on my side bar but never under my files. Can you tell me what that means?

Comment: Badly configured systems from neighbors?

Comment: Is your network secure? Are you seeing leaches on your network?

Comment: are you sure you didn't accidentally connect to your neighbors wifi?

Answer (score 0):

This may mean there are several people who have 'public sharing' enabled on some folders; people often do this when setting up a personal home network without realizing it. If you right click your network icon in the lower-right corner --> 'open network and sharing center' --> select 'change advanced sharing settings on the left-side' --> and observe "turn on network discovery" & Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the public folders." Make sure you are not broadcasting your own files.